# Express root of a polynomial in terms of a basis

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, roots

Let $ f(x) = x^3 + x + 1$. (Can assume that we already know that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$)

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Express $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\frac{1}{\alpha + 2}$ as a linear combination of $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2\}$.

So I was able to express $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ as a linear combination like so:

$$ f(\alpha) = 0 \implies \alpha^3 + \alpha + 1 = 0 \implies \alpha(\alpha^2 + 1) + 1 = 0 \implies \alpha(\alpha^2 + 1) = -1 \\\implies -\alpha^2 - 1 = \frac{1}{\alpha}$$

But, I'm stuck on the $\frac{1}{\alpha+2} $ part. I first tried to actually find a root of $f$, but it became too complicated, and I didn't think that was the best direction to go for this problem. I want to go for a similar strategy as I did for the first part, but nothing I tried has worked so far.

Comment: Use the Euclidean algorithm to write $1 = p(x)(x^3+x+1) + q(x)(x+2)$ (which can be done, since $x^3+x+1$ and $x+2$ must be relatively prime by the irreduciblility of $f(x)$). Now evaluate at $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the polynomial long division algorithm for dividing $\,x^3+x+1\;$ by $\;x+2\,.$

$x^3+x+1=\left(x^2-2x+5\right)\left(x+2\right)-9\,.$

Therefore, you get that

$\alpha^3+\alpha+1=\left(\alpha^2-2\alpha+5\right)\left(\alpha+2\right)-9\;\;,$

$0=\left(\alpha^2-2\alpha+5\right)\left(\alpha+2\right)-9\;\;,$

$9=\left(\alpha^2-2\alpha+5\right)\left(\alpha+2\right)\;\;,$

$\dfrac1{\alpha+2}=\dfrac19\alpha^2-\dfrac29\alpha+\dfrac59\;.$